# Java create x509certificate from XML X509Data

Tags: java, x509certificate

I extracted x509certificate data from a xml file

```
        <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>
      MIIB7DCCAVmgAwIBAgIQPjHcBTL63bBLuJZ88RcrCjAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMBExDzANBgNVBAMT
      BnJvbWVvazAgFw0xMDAzMTUwMjI1MjZaGA8yMTEwMDIxOTAyMjUyNlowETEPMA0GA1UEAxMG
      cm9tZW9rMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDAu/sBh13A27rR7gJpZsI6zCee
      TXNohQWlq2z6Zg8Oxzsy5JoVV....==
            </X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
```

How can I create Java X509Certificate from this data?

I've already tried

```
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance(X_509);
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes);
    X509Certificate x509cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bais);
    bais.close();
```

But an error occurs

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: invalid DER-encoded certificate data.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Certificate is base64-encoded, so you need to decode it first.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp:A `pem` doesn't need to be decoded. Java's certificate factory can handle it

Comment: @Cratylus you are genius! Thanks a lot. I got it. Eventually those bytes are PEM. And Java can handle it but if enclose it between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

Comment: @Cratylus yes, but that's not PEM.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp:I am not sure how you can tell this.From the answer it seems that it is a `pem`.

Comment: @cratylus If you need to add something to get X, then the original is not X.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp:But `pem` isn't already base64?

Comment: @cratylus Well, everything depends on what you call "PEM". Common tradition (not a standard) is to apply PEM abbreviation to base64-encoded data wrapped with prefix and suffix lines, possibly with headers. base64 data alone don't make the described PEM. Actually, the problem itself is the evidence - the code designed to load PEM can not load base64 data. Of course, if you call any base64-encoded data "PEM", then it's PEM.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp:I hadn't realize this before.And I strongly suspect that this is implementation dependent as well.Meaning that another provider (probably the one that actually was used to create this XML fragment) would not make such a distinction i.e. expect the headers.But I think what you point out is very important.

Comment: @nixspirit:You should tell that to my boss.... :P

Answer (score 1):

those bytes are PEM. And Java can handle it but if enclose it between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"