# Extract public key from an XML file with X509certificate?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, saml

I am trying to create an `X509Certificate2` object in C# from an XML file. The XML file is a `SAML` metadata file that we received from a vendor.

I am trying to extract the public key from these XML Elements:

```
<X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>
      MIIB7DCCAVmgAwIBAgIQPjHcBTL63bBLuJZ88RcrCjAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMBExDzANBgNVBAMT
      BnJvbWVvazAgFw0xMDAzMTUwMjI1MjZaGA8yMTEwMDIxOTAyMjUyNlowETEPMA0GA1UEAxMG
      cm9tZW9rMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDAu/sBh13A27rR7gJpZsI6zCee
      TXNohQWlq2z6Zg8Oxzsy5JoVV 
    </X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
```

Is there a way in C# to extract either the .cer file or public key from the XML element?

Comment: Looks like base64 encoded data there (but doesn't decode to X509 cert for me, according to openssl). Similar question (for Java) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13091272/27190.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer without knowing how the X509Certificate is encoded, but assuming you have the encoding stuff, you can do something like the following:

```
  var document = new XmlDocument();
  document.LoadXml(txtXml.Text);
  var cert = document.SelectSingleNode("X509Data/X509Certificate").InnerText;
  /*...Decode text in cert here (may need to use Encoding, Base64, UrlEncode, etc) ending with 'data' being a byte array...*/ 
  var x509 = new X509Certificate2(data);
```

Then you should be able to write the file to disk using standard File I/O logic.

Answer (score 9):

Randall's answer is correct. But in SAML Token the certificate I believe will always be Base64 encoded. 
So for posterity, the solution that worked for me was:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(txtXml.Text);
var certificateStr = document.SelectSingleNode("X509Data/X509Certificate").InnerText;
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateStr);
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(data);
Console.WriteLine("Public Key Format: {0}", x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true));
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!